# What is the purpose of derived data folder in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am new to Xcode can you kindly tell what is the purpose of folder derived data, I can see that Xcode outputs the build binaries in there, visual studio would normally make build folder within the project directory.

Is this derived data folder same as output folder or does it have any other significance too ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Derived Data

> **From the Documention**: Derived data consists of project indexes, logs, and build products
>   including intermediate build files.

↳ [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-projects_organizer/AboutProjectsWindow/AboutProjectsWindow.html)

So to answer your question, it more or less serves a similar role as the build folder in visual studio.